# Reopen request: "An interjection for expressing nostalgia"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I would like to request to reopen this question:

[An interjection/expression for expressing nostalgia](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170031/an-interjection-for-expressing-nostalgia)

It is not in the review list anymore.

I also rephrased for re-consideration. There is an answer that fits, and fits for all contexts as well. I think it is a helpful question with a helpful answer.

Thanks.

**Note:** Also, I don't understand why it is closed as primarily opinion-based. You can explain that too.  Even after I rephrased, is it still primarily opinion-based?

There can be common interjections (or expressions) used for nostalgia and I even gave an answer that is *not* primarily opinion based. And the question is put on hold and closed after I gave the answer.

Comment: I think the question was properly closed. It asks for an *interjection*, not an *expression*. And the only credible candidate (***Ah!***) can also be used in so many other contexts (surprise, pain, delight, disgust, sympathy, etc.) that it's barely worth even flagging up in the first place.

Comment: What about my answer?

Comment: Also we can modify it to "expression" if it is going to make it any better. Though interjections can be an expression too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - we've allowed questions about interjections before: thank God, [mother of God](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91844/understanding-mother-of-god-or-holy-mother-of-god), [God forbid](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38654/replacement-for-god-forbid), and many more that I remember. *Those* didn't seem OT.

Comment: @ermanen: I personally never closevoted in the first place, but I if I'd seen it with 3-4 closevotes already I almost certainly *would* have done. On the other hand, if it had asked for an "expression" rather than an "interjection", I probably *wouldn't* have done (other expressions, such as *"Good times!"*, come to mind). So yes - in exactly this context, that small change would have made a difference to me (if I'd been involved! :)

Comment: @Fumble: I re-edited the question to get your vote :)

Comment: You sly dog! :) I scrupulously never said I would vote to *reopen* - only that in the hypothetical case that I'd come across the question with 3-4 closevotes *before it was originally closed*, the *interjection/expression* distinction would have been enough to tip the balance for me. But I never felt *that* strongly about it, and it obviously bothers you, so I've voted to reopen.

Comment: It is re-opened. Thanks for the support everyone!